# Socket.IO for Unity - can't connect to external servers

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I'm using [Socket.IO for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721) and my own node.js server to make a multiplayer game in Unity.

Within my own computer, everything works fine, but when other people download my game to test it, they can't connect to my server. They *can* connect to the server through the browser, so they can access the server, just not through Unity.

At first I thought it was a firewall issue, but the first friend I tried it with doesn't even have an active firewall, and the other one I tested with exempted my game from his firewall.

Comment: First comment on that page says - Make sure you add "socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" to the end of your websocket url. Example: "ws://localhost:4567/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket"

Comment: @BrahmaDev yep I'm aware of that and it's not the issue.

Comment: did u finally solve the issue ?